# Индексация поисковиками javascript

Tags: javascript

Меняю с помощью JS  у документа title. Какой  из title - ов (до изменения или после) будет проиндексирован поисковиками?

Comment: Ну и имеем прямо противоположные ответы. Может, можно это как-либо проверить? Весь вопрос в том, как происходит индексация страниц поисковыми роботами. Если по исходному коду, то ответ очевиден

Comment: Создайте тестовую страницу с таким поведением и ссылки на нее разместите на индексируемых страница. Потом проверьте, как она в поиске поисковиков отобразится.

Comment: Раньше поисковые роботы не запускали пользовательские скрипты, сейчас вроде запускают, но как-то по странному. Собственно поэтому и появились изоморфные фрейворки). У гугла есть интересная [штука](http://noseo.blogopoisk.ru/2014/10/Fetch-as-Google.html), посмотрите с ее помощью.

Answer (score 3):

Проиндексирует старый title, ведь JavaScript работает на стороне клиента и никак не влияет на то, что генерируется сервером.

Comment: А гугл, например, скрипты js выполняет ;)

Comment: @Visman, про Google вы ошибаетесь. [Proof1](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more), [proof2](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992?hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

Если поисковый паук уже побывал на странице то будет старый title, а потом переиндексирует страницу и появится новый.

Comment: А есть подтверждение? `title` то меняется через `javascript`, а без него он как был старый, так и есть :)

Comment: возможно я не так понял вопрос) но тем не менее Google понимает JS

Comment: @Sergiks, http://ain.ua/2015/05/13/579922

Comment: @emtecif спасибо, не знал.